# Visitor visa refused!

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My cousin applied for a visitor's visa, to visit me as well as his extended family in the UK.

He had visited for 2 weeks after being granted 6 months last year. However we had decided that he should perhaps apply for a 2-year visa this time.
However he was refused based on these reasons:

[image]

[image]

How do we rectify these points stated and can he reapply straight away?

Visa got refused again
[image: HELP HOW DO I CONVINCE ECO]

Comment: You applied for a visa for a trip that was 3 months and 22 days by submitting an application for a leave request from your job for just 90 days? Why exactly? Surely it would be better to submit an actual document that indicates approved leave has been granted for the entire duration of your trip?

Comment: The letter that the headquarters provide are standard letters...had my leave not been approved i wouldn't have received the letter. I applied to go on leave from the 8th of January to the 8th of April..

Comment: That still leaves 22 days unaccounted for? If you're going to reapply, that needs to be clarified.

Comment: I only need to spend 3 months..I don't know where they got the 22 days extra.. can you please give me pointers as to how to address these points...and can i re apply straight away or is there a cooling off period?

Comment: Please scan in the actual refusal in full, editing out your personal details as it's easy to unintentionally skip some important detail when transcribing it. Before you reapply you will have to address all ECO concerns - proof of your wife's immigration status, get an actual letter that confirms your leave (they default is clearly not up to par) and clarify the length of stay.

Comment: You say you sent a letter in which your leave is approved, but the visa officer understood it to be a letter of application. Maybe you could also scan and upload the letter (removing personal information). Also tell us the exact dates you told them you would be visiting the UK.

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload the letter...but I stated that i'ld like to depart from Jamaica on the 8th and return the 8th of April

Comment: You can upload it to some image hosting site and post a link, like imgur.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The visa office probably think you will remain illegally in the UK after arriving as a visitor because your spouse and child are in the UK and families normally want to be together.  You should get professional advice as you are likely to be refused a visit visa on this point alone.

Comment: Are u saying that it's pointless re-applying?

Comment: That's a pretty far-fetched assumption, what did you base it on? I don't see anything disputing ties to the local economy, more like holes in paperwork.

Comment: Someone posted that Its likely for me to.get refused again based on the fact that I have my wife and newly born baby in the U.K...so just wanted clarification as to whether or not that individual was stating that it was pointless trying to re-apply..

Comment: @SashaPowell I meant the original poster, this answer seems a bit far-fetched but we don't know enough to really help as we need a scan of the refusal letter.

Comment: Oh sorry...still trying to figure out how to upload it?

Comment: @sashapowell on reading the uploaded letter I withdraw my earlier answer. djclayworth's advice is good. Deal with each item in the refusal letter one by one in your next application. One point that I don't think was mentioned elsewhere here is evidence of your marriage, but the letter does mention it.

Comment: I sent a copy of my marriage certificate with the first application..

Comment: Would anyone advice on reapplying again for the 2 years...if i address these points..how likely would it be for me to be granted this time round?

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues you will need to address:

> However you have provided no evidence of [your wife's] current immigration status.

This means they need to see documentary evidence that your wife is legally in the UK, and will be for the time you are visiting. You will probably need to provide copies of her passport and visa.

> However the letter provided makes no mention of your leave being approved.

You need to get your employer to write you a letter saying that your 3 months leave has been approved, giving the dates, and send it with your next application.

> You have stated in your application that you wish to visit your spouse and cousins for a period of 3 months and 22 days.

You need to make sure that the dates you have proposed for your visit agree with the dates that your employer has approved for your leave. If your employer grants you 90 days leave, your visit schedule must allow you to return to the job before 90 days. It's possible that this is just an error by the processing officer, but you should make doubly sure you are clear about your itinerary in your next application.

Since no mention is made of finances I assume that the documents your provided satisfied them. You will have to explain how you can take 90 days away from your job and still afford to travel.

Comment: Thank you so much..when I'm on 3 months I do get holiday pay during this time, I will definitely get the letter more detailed from my employer and I will send the letter my wife received from the Home Office which outlines her status along with the conditions in which she is in the UK. However I will not be applying for 2 years this time ...Will just stick to the 6 months. As far as convincing them that I have no intentions of running off...how would I go about this please I need pointers..to ensure a better chance of visa being granted?

Comment: @SashaPowell ECO didn't seem to have an issue with you as a potential overstayer, as the formula "in the light of the above..." is what they usually put on most rejected application under app V 4.2. And as DJC explained, he had no issues with your finances or ties to the local community back home so you should be good to go once you address the issues listed here.

Comment: Thank u guys so much...your guidance have helped me so much