# UK visitor visa refused twice; lack of evidence

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Need to know how I can convince them

[image]

Comment: It was a standard visitors visa to the U.k, applied for a 6 months visa last February and spent time with my cousins and wife.I stayed for 2 weeks. But since then my wife fell pregnant so I applied for a 2 year visa..with the intention of travelling to visit them now and again whenever I get leave from work. However I got refused back in November under paragraph 4.2. So I reapplied in attempt to address the reasons they had highlighted, but got turned down again under the same paragraph.

Comment: You've now been refused twice, and judging by the paragraph in the refusal letter you've posted, the ECO is worried that you will not want to leave your wife and child in the UK while you return to Jamaica. I can see his point. I suspect that unless you can provide an exceptional case for returning to Jamaica you will continue to be refused. Don't apply again without taking expert legal advice (which you won't get by asking in the internet). Consult a lawyer who practices in UK immigration cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visitor visa refused!](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106025/visitor-visa-refused)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Answer (score 3):

Based on looking at your other question posted recently, this is actually your third refusal. There is almost no chance you will get a visa by asking advice on the internet and you need instead to get a lawyer *with experience of UK visa application cases*.

Comment: This is my second...I had sought advice and a lawyer was stating that all I needed was an Entry Clearance letter..what is an Entry Clearance letter?

Comment: @SashaPowell a visa, basically. It sounds like the lawyer you talked to isn't worth paying. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-is-entry-clearance-ecb03/ecb3-what-is-entry-clearance

Comment: I'm very disappointed that a lawyer would give such limited advice that you, the client, are left to ask this question on the internet. As @airsick says, you need a lawyer who practices in UK immigration cases. Your present lawyer is not specialised enough. A good lawyer will give you detailed advice about exactly what to do next and will review all your applications with you.

Comment: Ok...as she had me wondering what it was and how that would improve my chances of getting a visa. I'm starting to feel like there's no way I could convince them

Comment: Not convinced "get a better lawyer" is the best advice to give to the OP. Given the state of UK immigration at the moment, I don't think any lawyer is going to get him in, and he'd just be wasting his money.

Comment: @RupertMorrish the "state of UK immigration" is neither here nor there with regard to this application - an immigration lawyer would be able to advise the applicant on specifics and word the application perfectly, which is basically the only way out of serial refusals.  Or the immigration lawyer can advise the application is too weak to pursue.  Either way, it's better than being told "all you need is a visa" when being rejected for a visa...

Comment: @Moo ... assuming there is a way out. If there isn't, and there may not be, a lawyer is not going to help.

Comment: @RupertMorrish If the lawyer stops further weak applications, that's definitely "help" right there - just not "help to get into the UK *right now*" help.